# Using the parent module scope as a test dependency in the maven sub module

Tags: java, maven

I'm currently customizing my `boot-starter`:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring Boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Load basic framework. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- load database framework. -->

        <!-- Slf4j Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But i am not able to use `<scope>test</scope>` dependency in my submodule:

```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.chhtest.clc</groupId>
       <artifactId>boot-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

The way I can think of is:

1. Change `<scope>test</scope>` to `<scope>compile</scope>`
2. Submodules use parent

The first one will increase the size of my package, the second one looks good, but I want the parent of the submodule to be free to choose

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: If you are within a multi module setup use the parent... if it makes sense...

Comment: Yes, I think parent is very suitable for some public projects, but I'm currently customizing it for an internal system. I just need to introduce my boot starter for other modules. I don't want my A module to use spring web and B module to use spring webflux

Comment: Make the general setup in your own parent (root of the multi module) and use the import scope for the spring boot dependencies in each module you can decide which deps you will be using by defining spring-boot-maven-plugin where needed...

Comment: You're right!
I have been thinking for a while. If I design like this, I will be very painful in the later stage.
I should not limit which technology sub modules use, because they have different businesses to implement, and there will always be appropriate technologies to implement.
I'm trying to fix it, Thank you for your help

Comment: If this continues, there will be a large number of`<dependencyManagement>`and`<exclusions>`in my project in the later stage. I think this design will make business development easier, at least in the early stage. But once entering the large stage, the implementation technology options will no longer be limited to my initial settings, for example, the database will no longer be limited to `mysql` or `postgresql`

Comment: The given sentence `If this continues, there will be a large number of<dependencyManagement>and<exclusions>in my project in the later stage.` i don't understand? Why do you need exclusions?

Comment: I'm sorry to reply just now. I have been busy recently. Give me a moment. Let me supplement the relevant design drawings. I think we can set up a new discussion for this purpose

Comment: I added some information here: https://github.com/HaceraI/strange_structure

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a better solution!

Just define the test dependency in all service parent modules, Let's look at the code:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>service-auth</module>
    <module>service-xxxxx</module>
    <module>service-xxx</module>
    <module>service-xxxx</module>
    <module>service-xx</module>
    <module>service-x</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Core Framework Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.clc</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-framework-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${clc-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.clc</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-framework-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${clc-core.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: But in doing so, I actually sacrifice a little degree of decoupling. My ideal situation is that the service module only needs to care about the business implementation, and all frameworks are handed over to the core module for maintenance